# could not load modules on centos directory does not exist?

Tags: centos, iptables

im trying to allow ftp access on my server I am running Centos 5.x i have instantiated the correct rules in my iptables but when trying to load "ip_conntrack_ftp i get this error:

```
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.18-028stab091.2/modules.dep: No such file or directory
```

also I have check my modules directory and it contains nothing.

thank you.

Comment: Can you show the `insmod` command that you're using?

Comment: Furthermore, is this a physical server, or a virtual server running  OpenVZ/Virtuozzo?

Comment: i think the reason it is not there is because i am on a VPS I just figured that out...is there a way to allow ftp without the module

Comment: If you're certain that you can't load kmods, then asking a new question about kmod-less FTP will get better answers. Go ahead and answer your own question or if an answer that is satisfactory exists, upvote it and mark it as accepted and then go ahead and make a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a OpenVZ/Virtuozzo VPS, there is no way to load a kernel module. Time to move to a different VPS solution or a dedicated server.

See also "[When CentOS is not CentOS](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/OtherSpins)"

> We have noticed that a lot of people are offering something that they
>   call CentOS. But this something is in reality only based on CentOS and
>   it has been modified by the people making it available. This is
>   usually the case for hosters that provide a Linux VPS (Virtual Private
>   Server). This is usually accomplished using site hosting software like
>   CPanel or Plesk, or by using virtualization software like Virtuozzo or
>   OpenVZ
>
> These software projects use CentOS as their base but add or modify
>   some of the core components. For example OpenVZ require a different
>   kernel then the one that CentOS ships and CPanel provide their own
>   version of Apache and PHP.